# Missing records between INNER and LEFT JOIN

Tags: select, left-join, inner-join

`select id from table` = **260 595** records

`select id from table
   left join table2 on table2.id = table.parent` = **260 595** records

`select id from table
   inner join table2 on table2.id = table.parent` = **260 192** records

What is the easiest way to find out what records in `table` have wrong (nonexistent) join so I can correct them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id from table left join table2 on table2.id = table.parent
EXCEPT
select id from table inner join table2 on table2.id = table.parent
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this(it will give you id's in table that doesn't have corresponding records in table2):

```
select id 
  from table left join table2 
    on table2.id = table.parent
 where table.parent is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from table inner join table2 on table2.id <> table.parent
```